# How to convert a string-byte to a byte in Python

Tags: python, string, binary

I need something like that:

```
st = "1001000"
bt = toByte(st)
print(bt) # b'H'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for:

```
def tochr(bitstr):
    return chr(int(bitstr, 2))
```

or for a bytestring:

```
def tobyte(st):
    return bytes([int('1001000',2)])
```

For example:

```
>>> tochr('1001000')
'H'
>>> tobyte('1001000')
b'H'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. :-)